# Does Linux kernel know when a user is added by calling "useradd" command by a shell?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Does Linux kernel know when a user is added by calling "useradd" command by a shell?

Or, there is no reason to know it by the kernel?

Comment: No reason to know. The kernel doesn't care about users, only about user-IDs, and all IDs are valid.

Answer (score 2):

No, the kernel doesn't know.  And there is no reason that it needs to know.

The "useradd" command, the passwd files, the "login" program and so on take care of the mapping of user names / identities to uid numbers.  The kernel only knows, and only needs to know about the uid numbers.

Comment: I expected a answer like yours; your answer does make sense to me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

User management is strictly a userspace task. The kernel can know if the auth DB files have been accessed, but there is no guarantee that the operation involves adding a user specifically, and the system auth may use a network auth DB regardless.